# Get reliable monotonic time in c++(multiplatform)

Tags: c++, boost, time

I need a monotonic clock that can be used to calculate intervals.
Requirements:

- Must be monotonic, must not be influenced by the device time.
- Must not reset during an application session.(Same epoch for all return values in a session)
- Must represent real life seconds (not cpu seconds), must not be influenced by number of threads/processes running at that time.
- Seconds resolution is sufficient.

In my research I have found
Candidates:

- `std::clock()(ctime)` - Seems to use cpu seconds
- `boost::chrono::steady_clock()` - Does it use cpu seconds? Can the epoch change during an application `session(launch-end)`?
- Platform specific methods(`clock_gettime`, `mach_absolute_time`).

Did you ever encounter such a problem and what solution did you choose? Is `steady_clock()` reliable multiplatform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [std::chrono::steady_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock). By description it is not influenced by wall clock/system time changes and is best suitable for measuring intervals.

Answer (score 0):

> `boost::chrono::steady_clock()` - Does it use cpu seconds? Can the epoch change during an application session(launch-end)?

`std::chrono::steady_clock()` is specified to use real-time seconds and is not adjusted during sessions. I assume boost's implementation adheres to that. I have't had issues with `std::chrono::steady_clock` except that the resolution on some platforms is lower than others.